# About Classes and init method

Tags: python

I've just started coding a couple of days ago, and am stumbling with the OOP and classes part. Do we always need an `__init__` method? if not, when don't we need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not forced to write one.
You only need one when you actually set variables and their values at init time...

That said, in 99% of the time, you want to set variable passed to you, or maybe even some defaults...

```
class A(object):
    pass

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

someA = A() #creates an object of type A, with no custom variables or methods
someB = B('bar') #creates an object of type B, in which foo is set
```

Note, inheriting from object is called a new style class, and should be done. It is not mandatory...

Comment: Good explanation. But one quick note: In Python 3, even if you don't inherit from `object`, you still get a new-style class.

Comment: Also, it might be worth pointing out that (in a new-style class) if you don't write an `__init__`, you still have one—it's inherited from `object`, and it does nothing, but you can still see it, call it, etc.